# Wireshark dissector configuration argument

Tags: c, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have written a dissector for a custom protocol in Lua and I'm now going to refactor it in C. The issue is that the dissector requires some runtime arguments (decryption keys) that vary depending on the circumstances. In Lua this wasn't a problem since the required arguments can be hardcoded in and easily edited - same obviously does not apply to compiled C module.

How can I pass a configuration argument to Wireshark dissector? I can access it from a file system but that seems like a nasty way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a preference; see section 2.6 "User Preferences" in the `doc/README.dissector` file in the Wireshark source.  That way the user can set it through the Wireshark preferences dialogs or set it from the command line in Wireshark or TShark using the `-o` command-line flag.

Comment: From all the things I looked for, 'preference' somehow escaped me... Many thanks :)